# Can analyzing the data without creating a data frame in python for data loaded in database possible?

Tags: python

The data is stored in the DBeaver database.I would like to analyze my data through python without creating a data frame.And the python is installed in my computer. As the data is huge, creating a data frame will consume my ram and space.
So, it it possible to directly link my python code to the database and do the necessary aggregation or data manipulation and gather only the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you use python directly then also it will consume more ram and space. and if you do directly data analysis with database then it will may lead to unexpected results

instead you can use this [Dask Dataframe](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) from [Dask Official](https://dask.org/) ... [Dask Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dask_(software))

with dask dataframe you can do data analysis even if you have big dataset

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in which scale you want to work with your data and how big is your data set but if you are going to change the data in large scale i would recommend creating csv file which contains your dataset and working with pandas dataFrames reading csv files are fairly fast and easy to work if your interested you can visit here and read parts needed.

> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html